# SEM/MIMIC Model Using Covariates

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

I'm currently struggling with structural equation modeling. I have a model with three factors and would like to explore the impact of subject's sex and age on them.

How should I do it and – more importantly – how to report the results. Should I test every model (e.g., influence of age on factor 1 + 2 + 3, influence of age on factor 1 + 2 (not 3) etc..) or .. I'm really clueless as I never did something like this before.. Some paper recommendations would be absolutely helpful as well. I googled a lot and didn't find anything.

Also: When is it a  MIMIC model? Do the predictors have to be non-latent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put all your predictors into the model simultaneously, and they should predict every factor.

Yes, this is MIMIC (multiple indicator, multiple cause) model. It's a MIMIC because each factor has indicators - that is, measure variables which it points to, and multiple causes - that is, measured variables that point to it.

I don't know a paper off the top of my head, but it's a fairly straightforward model.

Comment: Thank you! Is it still a MIMIC when a predictor is latent?

Comment: No. But it's not a very interesting distinction to make.

Comment: Thank you again. One last question: Should I let the predictors correlate? Or is it 'enough' to insert both predictors into the regression, as in e.g. factor ~ age + gender

Comment: Yes, just as in regression, the predictors should correlate.

Comment: And when using gender and neuroticism as predictors, a regression path from gender to neuroticism should be implemented?

Comment: That's partly a theoretical question, and partly depends on what you actually want to test. I would probably just allow them to covary.